# Possible bug with GWT gwtquery .live() method

Tags: gwt, gwtquery

I'm trying to do the following:

I want to add a specific handler for some links, denoted by a class.

`$("a.link_list").live("click",  new ListLinkHandler());`

I need `.live()` instead of `.bind()` because new such links will be generated. (I know jQuery's `.live()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()`, but gwt-query doesn't have a `.on()` yet.)

I defined the handler like this (just as [the gwtquery example does](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted#Add_an_event_handler)):

```java
public class ListLinkHandler extends Function {
    @Override
    public boolean f(Event e) { [...] }
}
```

However, the handler method is never called when I click the links. 
I can see the event listener in Chrome Dev Tools: http://screencloud.net/v/bV5V. I think it's on the `body` because it's a `.live()`.

I tried using `.bind()` and it worked fine. The `body` event listener changed in a `a.link_list` and the handler does what it's supposed to do, but (as documented, I didn't test) not for newly created links.

I [filed a bug](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/issues/detail?id=173) for the `.live()` method, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Also, I have no idea how to do it without gwtquery, GWT doesn't seem to have a method for selecting elements by class, neither to continually add the listener to new elements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing something wrong, but I need more code to be sure. Could you send the complete `onModuleLoad` code which demonstrates this wrong behavior?

I have written a quick example using `live`, and it works either when adding new gwt widgets or dom elements with gquery, in both Chrome and FF

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  $("a.link_list").live("click",  new ListLinkHandler());

  // Add a new link via gquery
  $("<a class='link_list' href=javascript:alert('href') onClick=alert('onClick')>Click </a>").appendTo(document);

  // Add a new link via gwt widgets
  Anchor a = new Anchor("click");
  a.setStyleName("link_list");
  a.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      Window.alert("clickHandler");
    }
  });
  RootPanel.get().add(a);
}

public class ListLinkHandler extends Function {
  @Override
  public boolean f(Event e) {
    Window.alert("live");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome gquery! like manolo's example about the ability of adding behavior to gwt widgets added in future.

Comment: Ok, let me know if I can close the issue at https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/issues/detail?id=173 as well.